# Assign value to a column where column name is a concatenation of other columns' values

Tags: r, tidyverse

Assume the following data:

```
dat <- structure(list(row = c("467", "537", "236", "257"), x_11 = c(5, 
5, 5, 4), x_12 = c(5, 5, 6, 1), x_13 = c(4, 7, 6, 5), x_14 = c(4, 
6, 4, 1), x_15 = c(4, 5, 4, 4), x_16 = c(2, 6, 5, 2), x_17 = c(3, 
4, 3, 3), mode_1 = c(4, 5, 4, 1), mode_2 = c(NA, NA, 5, 4), mode_3 = c(NA, 
NA, 6, NA), mean = c(3.85714285714286, 5.42857142857143, 4.71428571428571, 
2.85714285714286), sd = c(1.0690449676497, 0.975900072948533, 
1.11269728052837, 1.57359158493889), nearest = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 14
  row    x_11  x_12  x_13  x_14  x_15  x_16  x_17 mode_1 mode_2 mode_3  mean    sd nearest
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
1 467       5     5     4     4     4     2     3      4     NA     NA  3.86 1.07        1
2 537       5     5     7     6     5     6     4      5     NA     NA  5.43 0.976       1
3 236       5     6     6     4     4     5     3      4      5      6  4.71 1.11        2
4 257       4     1     5     1     4     2     3      1      4     NA  2.86 1.57        2
```

I now want to create a new column based on the following condition:

- if mode_2 is NA, then take the value from mode_1
- if mode_2 is NOT NA, then take the value from the column ***position*** that is specified in "nearest". Note: the column position in "nearest" refers to the column position of the mode_ columns, NOT the overall column positions of the data frame.

I tried the following, but always getting an error that object "take" is not found:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(test = case_when(is.na(mode_2) ~ x_1,
                          TRUE ~ !!paste0("mode_", nearest))
```

Expected output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 15
  row       [...] mode_1 mode_2 mode_3  mean    sd nearest  test
  <chr>     [...]  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <int> <int>
1 467       [...]      4     NA     NA  3.86 1.07        1     4
2 537       [...]      5     NA     NA  5.43 0.976       1     5
3 236       [...]      4      5      6  4.71 1.11        2     5
4 257       [...]      1      4     NA  2.86 1.57        2     4
```

Note in reality I have ~ 20-50 mode_ columns so I can't hard code all potential combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new column which has corresponding value from `take` and use `coalesce` to select any one of the non-NA value.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(take_value = as.numeric(.[cbind(1:n(),
                                   match(paste0('x_', take), names(.)))]),
         test = coalesce(take_value, x_1)) %>%
  select(-take_value)

#  x_1 x_2 take test
#1   1  NA    2    1
#2   9   2    1    9
#3   3  NA    2    3
#4   7   8    2    8
#5   5  NA    1    5
```

---

Using base R :

```
dat$take_value <- dat[cbind(1:nrow(dat), match(paste0('x_', dat$take), names(dat)))]
transform(dat, test = ifelse(is.na(take_value), x_1, take_value))
```

Comment: This assumes that the x_1, x_2 columns are the first one so that you can access them via their column position. How would it work if I have e.g. a few other columns coming before x_1 and x_2, or more general: how would it work by accessing the columns by their name?

Comment: No...This assumes `take` has the column number from where the value has to be taken. What does `take` actually have?

Comment: so take has the column position of the x_ columns, not the overall column positions of the data frame. Sorry, I make this clearer in my post.

Comment: Still getting an error, probably because my toy data set doesn't show the whole complexity of my real data set. I see to update my input data frame in my post.

Comment: What error do you get? Does this work for you on the example you provided? How is your actual data different from the example you shared? What are your actual column names inplace of  `x_1`, `x_2`?

Comment: updated my post accordingly. Sorry for this back and forth.

Comment: With your code I'M getting the following error:

`Fehler: Problem with `mutate()` input `take_value`.
x Subscript `cbind(1:n(), match(paste0("mode_", nearest), names(.)))` is a matrix, it must be of type logical.
i Input `take_value` is `as.numeric(.[cbind(1:n(), match(paste0("mode_", nearest), names(.)))])`.`

Comment: @deschen matrix subsetting doesn't work on tibbles, turn it into dataframe. `dat <- data.frame(dat)` and try again. Or if you don't want to change `dat` from tibble to dataframe add it in the pipe `dat %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate(take_value = as.numeric......`